# How can I output the RGB value of a slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How would I output what the pointer RGB values are on a slider with a small color palette?

HTML:

```
<div>
<input class="slider" type="range" min="0" max="255" value="127" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slider {
display: inline;
-webkit-apperance: none;
height: 25px;
border-radius: 6px;
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255, 0, 0), rgb(255, 125, 0), rgb(255, 255, 0), rgb(125, 255, 0), rgb(0, 255, 0), rgb(0, 255, 125), rgb(0, 255, 255), rgb(0, 125, 255), rgb(0, 0, 255) );
outline: none;
width: 35%;
}
```

Also - is there an easier way to show those colors from red->blue than the method i did?

Comment: i don't see the colors on the slider with chrome, also there is a input type=color. in order to output the color, you would need to do some math with the input value, but it does not seem very complex to me.

Comment: What really you want to do?

Comment: Sounds like you want a slider for [hue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reliably determine the RGB value of a CSS gradient via a slider input, consider defining the colour values of your gradient via javascript. This gives you the ability to both:

- calculate the colour based on the slider value and
- specify the CSS gradient on the html (to guarantee consistency)

So for instance, in your script you could define the colour gradient via an array of colour values:

```
var colors = [
  [255, 0, 0], 
  [255, 125, 0], 
  [255, 255, 0], 
  [125, 255, 0], 
  [0, 255, 0], 
  [0, 255, 125], 
  [0, 255, 255], 
  [0, 125, 255], 
  [0, 0, 255]
];
```

You could then compute the background css value for your slider by means of the following:

```
slider.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right ' + 
colors.reduce(function(style, color) { return style + ', rgb('+color[0]+','+color[1]+','+color[2]+')'; }, '') + 
')';
```

Finally, you could assign a `change` event listener to your slider element, and use the `colours` array to derive the RGB color from the input's value:

```
// The change event is defined on the input event
input.addEventListener('change', function(event) {

    // Derive lookup index from input element attributes
  var max = event.target.max;
  var min = event.target.min;
  var range = (max - min);

  // Calculate current lookup index to fetch current and next colour
  var frac = event.target.value / event.target.max;
  var offset = (colors.length - 1) * frac;
  var index = Math.min(Math.floor(offset), colors.length - 2);

  // Extract current and next colour from current slider position
  var colorNext = colors[ index + 1 ];
  var colorCurr = colors[ index ];
  var colorFrac = offset - index;

    // Linear interpolation utility used to compute blend between current and next colour
  function mix(from, to, frac) {
    return parseInt((to - from) * frac + from);
  }

    // Compute colour values for each channel
  var r = mix(colorCurr[0], colorNext[1], colorFrac);
  var g = mix(colorCurr[1], colorNext[1], colorFrac);
  var b = mix(colorCurr[2], colorNext[2], colorFrac);

    // The current colour based on slider position
  console.log('rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')')
})
```

For a full working demo, [please see this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/736m5j81/26/) - hope that helps you!

### Update

Please ensure your HTML is updated to:

```
<div class="slider">
<input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="127" />
</div>
```

And your CSS is updated to:

```
.slider {
display: block; 
height: 25px;
border-radius: 6px; 
outline: none;
}

.slider input { 
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I really like this!.. although, I can't get it to work. I tried altering my code for it then just created a new one and copied this but all that's appearing is just the 'range input' with no colors. This part is adding to the style, right? The CSS doesn't need to indicate it anymore? "slider.style.background = 'linear-gradient(to right"

Comment: @Brandon glad I could help! This may be due to your HTML and CSS needing updating as well (see updates to answer above, taken from the provided jsFiddle) - hope that helps you!